# customise site search so a parent type is returned based on it's children's content

Tags: plone

I have a dexterity content type which is folderish and I would like to have it show up in search results based on it's child's content (pdfs etc). Is this possible, where and how would this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to reindex the `searchableText` of the children on the parent and not on the item itself (concatenate the searchableText of all children).

Your new searchableText Index could look like this:

```python
@indexer(IYourContainerType)
def SearchableText(obj):
    searchable_text = obj.SearchableText()

    for item in obj.getFolderContents({'portal_type': 'File'}, full_object=True):
        searchable_text += item.SearchableText()
    return searchable_text
```

Now you have to subscribe some events, because the SearchableText of the container needs to be updated automatically on changes in the container.

Handle if:

1. something is added to the Container
2. something is removed from the container
3. something is modified in the Container

[Docu for Events in Plone](http://developer.plone.org/components/events.html#event-types)

The eventhandler could look like this:

```python
def reindex_container(obj, event):
    parent = aq_parent(aq_inner(obj))

    if not IYourContainerType.providedBy(parent):
        return

    catalog = getToolByName(obj, 'portal_catalog')
    # Only reindex existing brains! The parent may be just
    # deleted, we should not put it back in the catalog.
    parent_path = '/'.join(parent.getPhysicalPath())
    if catalog.getrid(parent_path) is not None:
        parent.reindexObject()
```

Probably you need to handle `MOVE` separately.

Comment: Does this @indexer & event handler code go in myContainerType.py? The search results aren't turning up child items: how should I test these components individually?

Comment: @Adripants I usually create a module called `indexers.py` and `handlers.py`. You can test the new searchableText Index separately - Create a container, add some items with text, call the the searchableText index on the container. Please consider the Docu about indexes/metadata in plone and how to register a new index: https://developer.plone.org/searching_and_indexing/indexing.html#id10