# Update SearchableText index on dexterity type

Tags: plone, dexterity

I am trying to update SearchableText on my dexterity type ("Resource"), to include file contents from child items, by adding this to resource.py:

```
@indexer(IResource)
def subFiles(obj):
    searchable_text = obj.SearchableText()

    for item in obj.getFolderContents({'portal_type': 'File'}, full_object=True):
        searchable_text += item.SearchableText()
    return searchable_text

grok.global_adapter(subFiles, name="SearchableText")
```

I know I need an event to update this, but believe I should be able to see the index modified by manually "clearing and rebuilding" from the ZMI, however no changes take place on the value of SearchableText for objects of this content type. I am not seeing any errors either, so I am not sure where the problem lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did not recognise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154127/customise-site-search-so-a-parent-type-is-returned-based-on-its-childrens-cont/21155791?noredirect=1#comment32735523_21155791), that you are using dexterity.

You need the `dexteritytextindexer` behavior:
https://github.com/collective/collective.dexteritytextindexer

Enable this on your container type.

```xml
<property name="behaviors">
    <element value="collective.dexteritytextindexer.behavior.IDexterityTextIndexer" />
</property>
```

With the dexteritytextindexer you have a different approach to index the data on your container. Check the `dexteritytextindexer.IDynamicTextIndexExtender`.

Comment: Making the addition listed under zcml gives: ConfigurationError: ('Invalid value for', 'factory', "ImportError: Couldn't import hccrems.types.indexer, No module named indexer in .indexer.MySearchableTextExtender")

Comment: My type is 'resource', so should it be .resource.MySearchableTextExtender ? That doesn't throw an error, but the Searchable text isn't changing either.

Comment: The last paragraph confuses me. How do I know if my dexterity content type is using a "defined factory"?

Comment: You should not mix zcml and grok, register your adapters with zcml or with grok, it's a little bit messy if you use both. I use zcml, because it's imho easier to read/find components. yes grok is pythonic, but not in the plone core. Do you have a indexer.py, or do you define the index in your type.py? can you paste all your relevant code?

Comment: resource.py: http://pastie.org/9262685l resource.xml: pastie.org/8999579 hccrems.types.resource.xml: pastie.org/8999581 configure.zcml: pastie.org/8999582

Comment: Your `MySearchableTextExtender` class is not in a module named `indexer` it's in `resource.py`. Change `factory=".indexer.MySearchableTextExtender"` to `factory=".resource.MySearchableTextExtender"`